# How to update the Table Of Contents in Word Online?

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, table-of-contents

Is there a way to update the Table Of Contents of a document inside Word Online (Office 365)?

The only solution I've found consists in clicking the button *EDIT IN WORD* to edit the online file with the Word application installed locally, update the TOC there, then go back to Word Online, but it's a damn twisted way to do so.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Editing it in the Desktop version is the only method available at this time.

I agree it's a twisted method.

Comment: Thanks.  To be honest, given the cumbersomeness of Microsoft software, I was expecting this answer.

Comment: That's a shame. I'm a Linux user, so that method is not available to me.

Comment: Actually, it works now by right-clicking on the table of contents and then pressing "Update Table", even though the "References" > "Table of Contents" > "Update Table of Contents" is still grayed out.

Comment: not true nowadays

Answer (score 3):

In Word Online, first make sure the cursor is somewhere within the table of contents, then choose the menu item **References | Table of Contents | Update Table of Contents**.

[image: References | Table of Contents | Update Table of Contents]

(If the cursor is not in the TOC, then that menu item will be inactive and grayed out.)

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the references tab, you can select, update table of contents.